# how to update two connected models separatly in keras?

Tags: keras

I have two CNN model, which connected like this.

model1(input1, output)
 model2(model1.output, output2)

I want update each models separately every iteration and save weight separatly, but I don't know how to make this using keras model compiler and fit generator.

I coded like this for training operation

model1.compile(optimizer=..., epochs=500)
 model2.compile(optimizer=..., epochs=500)

but I don't want model2 get model1 output which training operation is finished.
 I want get model1 ouput at every iterations.

model1 is generate a image and model2 refines output of model1.
 I want to train with separate backpropation because each part has a different role.

for every iteration
 model1(input1, output)
 update model1(loss(output))

model2(model1.output, output2)
 update model2(loss(output2))

Answer (score 0):

Build your model 1, compile it, freeze the layers of model 1 and then build model 2 with them, then compile model 2.

If you now train model 2 the weights of model 1 will not be updated.

[How you can freeze layers in keras.](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-freeze-keras-layers)